# Changing values of another form from a separate form (solution not working)

Tags: c#, winforms

peoples. 
Today I'm attempting to change the background image of a panel from a separate form. I've looked at a few S.O. questions and they have all said to create a new form variable and change it's values. So, I've done this, and I don't get any errors, but I also don't get 
any change to the background. Here's what I mean: (this is the main form I'm trying to change)

```
public static void changeGridSize(int newSize)
        {
            Form_Main frm = new Form_Main();
            switch (newSize) 
            {
                case 16:
                    frm.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_16;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    frm.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_32;
                    break;
                case 64:
                    frm.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_64;
                    break;
                case 128:
                    frm.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_128;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And here is the other form:

```
int newSize = 16;
Form_Main.changeGridSize(newSize);
```

It's most likely something stupid but I'm stumped on this one.

**EDIT**

Here the files

Main form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LWJSGL_Level_Editor
{
    public partial class Form_Main : Form
    {
        public static int gridSize = 32;
        public Image pbg 
        {
            get { return this.panelBoard.BackgroundImage; }
            set { this.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = value; }
        }
        public String curTile = "";
        public Form_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonTile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //show file dialog
            openFileDialogTile.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void openFileDialogTile_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            curTile = openFileDialogTile.FileName;
            Msg(curTile);
        }

        public void Msg(String str)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }

        private void buttonSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form_Settings fs = new Form_Settings();
            fs.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void changeGridSize(int newSize)
        {
            switch (newSize) 
            {
                case 16:
                    this.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_16;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    this.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_32;
                    break;
                case 64:
                    this.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_64;
                    break;
                case 128:
                    this.panelBoard.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.grid_16;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Other form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LWJSGL_Level_Editor
{
    public partial class Form_Settings : Form
    {
        int newSize;

        public Form_Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonSaveSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //save settings
            Form_Main.gridSize = newSize;
            Form_Main frm = new Form_Main();
            frm.changeGridSize(newSize);
            this.Close();
        }

        private void radioButtonGridSize16_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newSize = 16;
        }

        private void radioButtonGridSize32_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newSize = 32;
        }

        private void radioButtonGridSize64_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newSize = 64;
        }

        private void radioButtonGridSize128_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newSize = 128;
        }

        private void Form_Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Form_Main.gridSize)
            { 
                case 16:
                    this.radioButtonGridSize16.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    this.radioButtonGridSize32.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case 64:
                    this.radioButtonGridSize64.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case 128:
                    this.radioButtonGridSize128.Checked = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Extension method must be defined in non-generic static class error is occuring on line 13 of the main form.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? your `panelBoard` is on your `Form_Main` but you still want to change its BackgroundImage from another `Form_Main`?

Comment: You are changing a new instance of Main_Form, probably not the one you are viewing. the frm variable should be assigned to the current instance of the form.

Comment: @KingKing yes I need to change it from a different form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your "other" form needs an instance of the main form (`Form_Main`), which you have stored as a variable named `frm`. With this variable you can call the main form instance, like this:

```
frm.changeGridSize(newSize);
```

Instead you are trying to call the form like it is a static class by using the syntax:

```
Form_Main.changeGridSize(newSize);
```

To get the instance of the main form to the "other" form, you can pass it to the constructor of the other form, like this:

```
public class OtherForm : Form
{
    Main_Form _mainForm;

    // Constructor
    public OtherForm(Main_Form theMainForm)
    {
        _mainForm = theMainForm;
    }

    public static void changeGridSize(int newSize)
    {
        _mainForm.changeGridSize(newSize);
    }
}
```

Finally, when you are creating your "other" form, you will need to pass an instance of the main form, like this:

```
OtherForm theOtherForm = new OtherForm(this);
```

Comment: I tried to change it and now it won't stop saying Extension method must be defined in non-generic static class, even after I put it back to how it was D:

Comment: Okay, I am confused, is the `changeGridSize` method in the main form or the other form? Can you post your current code with the extension method error message and the line that the message is occurring on?

Comment: Okay, where is `panelBoard` defined? Did you drag a panel on the form through the designer? Second, where is your reference to the main form in the settings form? You can pass `this` to the constructor of the settings form, as described in my answer? Also, which line is line 13, there are no line numbers in your posted code so I am not sure, just write the line text instead of referencing non-existent line numbers.

Comment: I did drag it onto the designer. The thing about the passing this I took out because it caused the Extension method must be defined in non-generic static class error. It's this line: public partial class Form_Main : Form

Comment: @JordanFitz - did you change these lines: `Form_Main.gridSize = newSize; Form_Main frm = new Form_Main(); frm.changeGridSize(newSize); this.Close();`? These need to use the variable defined in the class that is assigned to the reference of the main form in the constructor.

Comment: It turns out that the error was a bug or something in VS. All I had to do was restart it.

Comment: @JordanFitz - no problem, I was starting to wonder what happened to your project. Glad/sad it was just VS flaking out. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the variable in the specific instance of the form that you want to change. I would recommend adding the form as a parameter of your method or convert your static method to an extension method.

Parameter:

```
public static void changeGridSize(Form_Main frm, int newSize)
{
    switch (newSize)
```

Extension Method:

```
public static void changeGridSize(this Form_Main frm, int newSize)
{
    switch (newSize)
```

Usage of the extension method would be from the calling form:

```
myFormMain.changeGridSize(newSize);
```