# Get Text from text box on Form1 when calling function on Form2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Background/Context**

So I am building a program that take 2 Excel Files and compares them highlight the differences. This is working fine. Now i am developing a second form, which does a very similar thing but essentially "Applies" the changes. Now in the first form I have two text boxes which contain the file locations, however on the second form which appears after the changes are highlighted there is only an Apply button hence I need to pull down the text box path for the file from Form1 however this doesn't seem to work in mt code:

**CODE**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnApply1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnApply_Click);
        btnCancel1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnCancel1_Click);
    }

    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL"))
            {
                clsProcess.Kill();
                break;
            }
        }

        new CRCCompareWorksheets.CompareHelper().ApplyChanges(
            form1.ExcelPath1.Text, form1.ExcelPath2.Text, "CRC");
    }

    private void btnCancel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new CRCCompareWorksheets.CompareHelper().CancelApplication();
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

So at the line where i call the function for Applying the changes, the variables `form1.ExcelPath1.Text` and `form1.ExcelPath1.Text` are both blank hence the file locations are not being pulled through and nothing works :(

Comment: You are creating a new instance of Form1 in your Form2. I assume this is not the same form that you created and which has the text fields populated. I don't think you should have two forms, but if you insist on keeping them both (instead of adding an apply button on the first form), you need to pass the actual instance of form1 to form2 or just pass the text from its textboxes.

Comment: You can make static `string` fields in your forms and initialize them with text from textboxes, and access them from another class.

Comment: Does Form1 launch Form2?  In form2, you just have new Form1, so it doesn't have any values set on it.  Maybe you need to pass Form1 into Form2 when you create it?

Comment: That's the quadrillionst SO question dealing with passing this data to that form.

Comment: The ideal solution to this is to use a shared object as then if both forms are updating the same object they have the same data available to them,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing values of another form from a separate form (solution not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303975/changing-values-of-another-form-from-a-separate-form-solution-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that you create a new Instance of `Form1`. I guess, that `Form2` is opened by `Form1`. In that case I would provide a reference of the calling form to the newly generated `Form2`. This could look something like the following:

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    Form1 form1 = null;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
        btnApply1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnApply_Click);
        btnCancel1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnCancel1_Click);
    }

    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL"))
            {
            clsProcess.Kill();
            break;
            }
        }

        new CRCCompareWorksheets.CompareHelper().ApplyChanges(form1.ExcelPath1.Text, form1.ExcelPath2.Text, "CRC");
    }
    private void btnCancel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new CRCCompareWorksheets.CompareHelper().CancelApplication();
    }
}
```

In `Form1` you would then need to change the calling of `Form2` to something like this:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
frm.Show();
```

Additionally it would be good practice to create properties for the values you want to read from the `TextBoxes` instead of making the controls public:

```
// Properties in Form1
public string ExcelPath1Text
{
    get
    {
        return this.ExcelPath1.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        this.ExcelPath1.Text = value;
    }
}

public string ExcelPath2Text
{
    get
    {
        return this.ExcelPath2.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        this.ExcelPath2.Text = value;
    }
}
```

And then use the properties in `Form2`:

```
CRCCompareWorksheets.CompareHelper().ApplyChanges(form1.ExcelPath1Text, form1.ExcelPath2Text, "CRC");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this has solved the issue! Would you happen, after i get these 2 files, i open them up in an invisible instance of excel through the line `ExcelWkb1 = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile1);` however now it says that "Couldnt find file, possible it has been moved?" even though it definitely hasnt been touched or made read-only or anything... any idea what could be going on to cause this?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. You should post that in a separate question. The right people with more Excel Interop knowledge will take a look into it

Comment: Fair enough, ill look into it myself for now. Thanks for you help though!

Comment: @SBozhko are you using absolute or relative file paths? if relative then the location you are looking for the files may not be the one you think you are

Comment: @MikeT The user puts in the path of the file on Form1 so i assume its absolute

Comment: @SBozhko in that case it could also be permissions, as if you don't have permission to access the file then its the same as the file not being there

Comment: @MikeT Yeah i thought that too but i checked that the file was open and editable, seemed fine :L

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are creating a new form1 in form2, rather than using the existing form1 that has the data you want to pass to form2.

You should pass form1 to the form2 constructor:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = { get; set; }

    public Form2(Form form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
        btnApply1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnApply_Click);
        btnCancel1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnCancel1_Click);
    }
```

And when you create form2 (I assume this is in form1):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```